# How to create 2 divs with equal height without bootstrap or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a code is CSS and normal javascript but it won't work. Here is my code (HTML and CSS).

```css
.wrapper{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    .first{
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .second{
        vertical-align:top;
        display: inline-block;
        flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="first">
                <div class="times">
                    <div><h1>TIMES</h1><br></div>
                    <div class="space">
                        <h2>TIMES</h2>
                        <p>GESLOTEN</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space">
                        <h2>Dinsdag - Zaterdag</h2>
                        <p>09:30 UUR - 18:00 UUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <div class="welcome">
                    <div><h1>WELKOM</h1></div>
                    <div><p>TEKST</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried everything, at least I think I have.
The problem is that I can't fix this in CSS but I tried Java.
Still no success. Can someone please explain why I can't get it the same height.

It's a school project and I need to make a website from scratch.
Here is my full website source code: https://codepen.io/crosso_7/pen/VERrvQ

Comment: Actually, those are have same height. if you give background to them you can see. https://codepen.io/truetiem/pen/wYOrLR

Comment: @TrueTiem I have tried it and it looks horrible. https://imgur.com/a/zXFJvqV Background is #000 (black)

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: @SandipNirmal I am pretty new to this so I have no clue what you mean with flexbox

Comment: @CrossProduction Added code in the answer. Please check.

Comment: @CrossProduction do you want it to looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/tZiMHIm.png

Comment: @TrueTiem Yes but that black part needs to be white. How did you do that ? With padding?

Comment: @SandipNirmal Still no effect

Comment: @CrossProduction Just add a white background, not black :d Those are already have same height. Just their background is transparent, you can't see.

Comment: @CrossProduction Can you add fiddle or codeSandbox link. Will try to fix it there

Comment: @TrueTiem OMG it worked thank you. Pls reply with an answer so i can aprove yours.

Comment: @SandipNirmal I appriciate it bro but TrueTiem already helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `flexbox`. Something like this code snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper div {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 flex: 1;
 margin: 10px;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>asasasa</h2>
 </div>
 <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both first and second divs are actually the same height - I just copied your snippet and applied a border around each div to see the issue and both divs are equal.

```css
.wrapper{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    .first{
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        flex: 1;
        border: solid 1px blue;
    }

    .second{
        vertical-align:top;
        display: inline-block;
        flex: 1;
        border: solid 1px red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="first">
                <div class="times">
                    <div><h1>TIMES</h1><br></div>
                    <div class="space">
                        <h2>TIMES</h2>
                        <p>GESLOTEN</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space">
                        <h2>Dinsdag - Zaterdag</h2>
                        <p>09:30 UUR - 18:00 UUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <div class="welcome">
                    <div><h1>WELKOM</h1></div>
                    <div><p>TEKST</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the first div the one thats higher? It's probably created by the padding from first div content vs seconds less content.

May have to set first and second div with a px or % height which are the same to make it equal.

Comment: I have the height set to 100% still nothing. I also have tried auto but it has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the code below in your *.first* and *.second* divs

```
flex: 1;
display: flex;
```